# Изменить расположение кнопко для окна

Tags: wpf, .net, mahapps-metro

Как изменить расположение кнопок управления окном?
Использую библиотеку MahApps.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо кнопки для закрытия, сворачивания и разворачивания перенести в верхний правый угол.

Код стиля для кнопок рядом взял с их сайта, переносить их есть возможность, а вот с кнопками для окна не могу разобраться.

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="JRGrace.MainWindow"
                  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                  xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
                  xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:JRGrace"
                  Title="MainWindow" 
                  TitlebarHeight="150"
                  Height="350" Width="525">

<Controls:MetroWindow.TitleTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
               TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
               VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
               Margin="8 -1 8 0"
               FontWeight="Light"
               FontSize="{DynamicResource WindowTitleFontSize}"
               FontFamily="{DynamicResource HeaderFontFamily}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Controls:MetroWindow.TitleTemplate>

<Controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
    <Controls:WindowCommands VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Button Content="settings" />
        <Button>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Width="20"
               Height="20"
               Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}, Path=Foreground}">
                    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_cupcake}" />
                    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                </Rectangle>
                <TextBlock Margin="4 0 0 0"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Text="deploy cupcakes" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
    </Controls:WindowCommands>
</Controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>

<Grid>

</Grid>
```

Вот два варианта, как на данный момент видится шапка программы.
Title, Port и Clock - это отдельные вьюшки, которые уже реализованы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: о каких кнопках речь?

Comment: А как у вас размещено в окне `Controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands`?

Comment: @VladD: Обновил вопрос. Это тестовый пример.

Comment: @FoggyFinder кнопки закрытия, сворачивания и разворачивания. Сейчас они находятся по вертикали посередине (на картинке видно), а нужно поднять их вверх.

Comment: @UporotayaPanda: `TitlebarHeight="150"` выглядит как-то подозрительно. Вам надо именно столько?

Comment: @VladD: примерно да, я только сел писать View и надеюсь, что получиться засунуть туда необходимый контент...вот и решил опробовать на тестовом окне...

Comment: Непонятно, а зачем вам контент в titlebar’е? Почему не в основном контенте страницы?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71616/discussion-between-uporotayapanda-and-vladd).

Comment: @UporotayaPanda: Сорри, уже наверное завтра, а то поздно...

Comment: @Vlad: в Беларуси уже скоро утро) окей, буду ждать ответа)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если мы заглянем при помощи Snoop (или встроенного в свежие версии Visual Studio Live Visual Tree) в визуальное дерево, мы обнаружим, что за `RightWindowCommands` отвечает контрол типа `WindowButtonCommands`.

Мы там же увидим, что он растянут по высоте Title Bar'а. А значит, его можно прижать вверх, задав свойство `VerticalAlignment` при помощи стиля.

Пишем:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Controls:WindowButtonCommands">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
    </Style>
</Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
```

Явное задание высоты понадобилось потому, что иначе кнопки получались слишком сплюснутыми.

Пространство имён `Controls` определяется как в вопросе:

```
xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
```